# How to create an event handler when screen size (dimensions) in python?

Tags: python, event-handling, screen-size, qtgui

I'm using
screen = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
to obtain screen size (dimensions).

I'm looking for a sample code to notify when the screen size changes to update some measurements.

Thanks

Comment: Creating a thread that houses a while-statement might do it? Then use sleep() to run it every x seconds..

Comment: Thanks. But, I don't want to add any sort of timers plus I need to do the calculation once the change happens without waiting. Reducing the duration can help, but adds unneeded time burden.